# Replace matched pattern with different font

Tags: regex, vba, replace, outlook

I am using **Outlook 2010**, and I am trying to write a *macro* to replace the font of text with a different one, if it matches a pattern.

The logic I am trying to apply is simple - in the *user selected text*, check for a pattern, and on match, change the font for the matched text.

So far I have been able to split the text and apply/check regex, but the replacement is something that I am not clear on how to do.

```
Dim objOL As Application
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objSel As Object
Dim regEx As RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim m As Match
Dim lines As Variant
Dim ms As String

Set objOL = Application
Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

lines = Split(objSel, Chr(13))
For i = 0 To UBound(lines) Step 1
  Set regEx = New RegExp
  With regEx
    .Pattern = "\[(ok|edit|error)\](\[.*\])?" ' <-- this is just one regex, I want to be able to check more regexes
    .Global = True
  End With
 If regEx.Test(lines(i)) Then
  Set matches = regEx.Execute(lines(i))
  For Each m In matches
     ms = m.SubMatches(1)
     ' ms.Font.Italic = True
     ' <-- here is where I am not sure how to replace! :( -->
  Next
End If    
Next i
```

P.S there seems to be *text-search* (`objSel.Find.Text`)and *replace* (`objSel.Find.Replacement.Text`) methods in `Selection` object, but not *pattern-search* ! (or I am missing it)

--EDIT--

Adding a sample text

```
user@host> show some data
..<few lines of data>..      <-- these lines as-is (but monospaced)
[ok][2014-11-26 11:05:02]
user@host> edit some other data
[edit data]
user@host(data)% some other command
```

1. I want to convert the whole block to a *monospaced* font (like `Courier New`, or `Consolas`)
2. And change the part that begins with `something@somewhere`.. and till `>` or `%` to dimmer color, 
   (i.e in this example `user@host>` and `user@host(data)%` dimmer/grey)
3. The rest in that line to bold  (**show some data** et al)
4. And, all the bracketed text followed by time-stamps (or without timestamps) similar to 2. (i.e, dim/grey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is getting closer to being done. The framework is here to make all sorts of changes now. Just need to get some of the regex patterns down to make the changes.

```
Sub FormatSelection()
    Dim objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector: Set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Dim objHtmlEditor As Object
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim Range As Word.Selection
    Dim objSavedSelection As Word.Selection
    Dim objFoundText As Object

    ' Verify a mail object is in focus.
    If objInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then

        ' Get the mail object.
        Set objMailItem = objInspector.CurrentItem

        If objInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            ' We are using a Word editor. Get the selected text.
            Set objHtmlEditor = objMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set objWord = objHtmlEditor.Application
            Set Range = objWord.Selection
            Debug.Print Range.Range


            ' Set defaults for the selection
            With Range.Font
                .Name = "Courier"
                .ColorIndex = wdAuto
            End With

            ' Stylize the bracketed text
            Call FormatTextWithRegex(Range, 2, "\[(.+?)\]")

            ' Prompt style text.
            Call FormatTextWithRegex(Range, 2, "(\w+?@.+?)(?=[\>\%])")

            ' Text following the prompt.
            Call FormatTextWithRegex(Range, 3, "(\w+?@.+?[\>\%])(.+)")


        End If

    End If

    Set objInspector = Nothing
    Set Range = Nothing
    Set objHtmlEditor = Nothing
    Set objMailItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub FormatTextWithRegex(ByRef pRange As Word.Selection, pActionIndex As Integer, pPattern As String)
    ' This routine will perform a regex replacement on the text in pRange using pPattern
    ' on text based on the pactionindex passed.
    Const intLightColourIndex = 15

    Dim objRegex As RegExp: Set objRegex = New RegExp
    Dim objSingleMatch As Object
    Dim objMatches As Object

    ' Configure Regex object.
    With objRegex
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = pPattern ' Example "\[(ok|edit|error)\](\[.+?\])?"
        .Global = True
    End With

    ' Locate all matches if any.
    Set objMatches = objRegex.Execute(pRange.Text)

    ' Find
    If (objMatches.Count > 0) Then
        Debug.Print objMatches.Count & " Match(es) Found"
        For Each objSingleMatch In objMatches
            ' Locate the text associated to this match in the selection so we can replace it.
            Debug.Print "Match Found: '" & objSingleMatch & "'"
            With pRange.Find
                '.ClearFormatting
                .Text = objSingleMatch.Value
                .ClearFormatting
                Select Case pActionIndex
                    Case 1  ' Italisize text
                        .Replacement.Text = objSingleMatch.Value
                        .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
                        .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
                        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                    Case 2  ' Dim the colour
                        .Replacement.Text = objSingleMatch.Value
                        .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
                        .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
                        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = intLightColourIndex
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                    Case 3  ' Bold that text!
                        .Replacement.Text = objSingleMatch.Value
                        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
                        .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
                        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End Select
            End With
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "No matches found for pattern: " & pPattern
    End If

    Set objRegex = Nothing
    Set objSingleMatch = Nothing
    Set objMatches = Nothing
End Sub
```

So we take what the user has selected and execute the macro. I have my Outlook configured with Word for the editor so that is tested for. Take the selected text and run the regex query against the text saving the matches.

The issue you had is what to do with the match once you found it. In my case since we have the actual text that matched we can run that through a find and replace using the selection once again.  Replacing the text with itself instead styled as directed.

**Caveats**

My testing text was the following:

> asdfadsfadsf [ok][Test]dsfadsfasdf asdfadsfadsfasdfasdfadsfadsf [ok][Test]dsfadsfasdf asdfadsfadsfasdf

I had to change your regex in your sample to be less greedy since it was matching both `[ok][Test]` sections. I don't know what kind of text you are working with so my logic might not apply to your situation. Test with caution.

You also had a comment that you needed to test multiple regexes... regexies.... I don't know what the plural is. Wouldn't be hard to create another function that calls this one for several patterns. Assuming this logic works repeating it should not be a big deal. I would like to make this work for you so if something is wrong let me know.

**Code Update**

I have changed the code so that the regex replacement is in a sub. So what the code does right now is change the selected text to courier and italisize text based on a regex. Now with how it is set up you can use the sub routine `FormatTextWithRegex` to make changes. Just need to update the pattern and action index which will perform the different styles. Will be updating this again soon with more information. Right now all that exists is the structure that I think you need.

Having issues with the bolding still but you can see the grey part is working correctly. Also the since this relies on highlighting the multiple calls to the function are causing an issue. Just not sure what it is.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the example and it did italicize the bracketed texts - like `[ok]` . I have edited the Q to add a sample of the text that I am trying to work with.

Comment: @vyom Still a work in progress but have a look at my latest. Having issues with the regex in VBA and right now text that matches outside the selection is also getting replaced. Have a look at what we have so far though. I dont want to keep on this direction if we are going the wrong way.

Comment: nice - now I see that the prompt is being italicised and the selection is changed to monospace. This is a good start. I just have to make the command bold.

Comment: BTW, if you think of any modifications/improvements, please update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have the grey highlighting down. Having a bugger of a time getting the bold to work. Its just regex in VBA is a little crippled. I will get it.

Comment: @vyom Closer still. Bugs to be worked out. Take this for a test drive at least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65735/discussion-between-vyom-and-matt).